# call javascript object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

This is probably a very easy question but let's say I have a php json_encoded javascript object of this form:

```
var js_objet = {
    "1": {
        "Users": {
            "id": "14",
            "name": "Peter"
         }, 
         "Children": [
             {
                 id: 17, 
                 name: "Paul"
             }, 
             {
                 id: 18, 
                 name: "Mathew"
             }
        ]
      }    
    }
```

What is the synthax to get the name of the child with id 18 (Mathew) for example from that Object?

Thank you

Comment: It's actually not that simple!  You'll have to write a custom function to do a findById for your custom JSON structure.

Comment: var n = js_objet["1"]["Children"][1].name

Answer (score 1):

Here's such a custom function as mentioned earlier.

```
function getChildrenById(id){
    for (var child in js_objet[1].Children){
        if(id == js_objet[1].Children[child].id){
            return js_objet[1].Children[child].name;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

running `getChildrenById(18)` would return "Mathew"

Hope that helps,

R.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var name = js_objet["1"].Children[1].name;
```

[JSFiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/4uRRk/)

Comment: I get `Cannot read property 'Children' of undefined`

Comment: I've edited my answer. I've mistyped variable name (it should be `js_objet` instead of `s_objet`)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach this problem:

```
var id = 18;
var name = '';
var jsObjIndex = "1";
var jsObjAttr = "Children"
for (var i = 0; i < js_objet[jsObjIndex][jsObjAttr].length; i++)
{
    if (js_objet[jsObjIndex][jsObjAttr][i].id == id)
    {
        name = js_objet[jsObjIndex][jsObjAttr][i].name;
        break;
    }
}
```

You are basically performing a linear search on every element of jsObjIndex.Children. There are likely better solutions however :).

Answer (score 0):

This really is a comment, but I don't have enough reputation (but it's relevant as I recently encountered the same issue): This would probably be easier to do if you can change the JSON format to use the ID as the key for each child object:

```
var js_objet = {
"1": {
    "Users": {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Peter"
     }, 
     "Children": {
         "17":{ 
             "name": "Paul"
         }, 
         "18":{
             "name": "Mathew"
         }
    }
  }    
}
```

Then you can simply call it using

```
js_objet[1].Children[18].name;
```

This is assuming each ID is unique.